# Android Google+ API doesnt work on permission revoked

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm using the Google+ API in my android application to login. Everything works fine. The dialog pops up which asks for the permissions, a token is get and so on. When I go into the secure settings of my google account and revoke the permissions for my app manually nothing works anymore. Google doesn't recognize that it needs to ask again for permission. The popup simply doesn't come up.

Can anyone help me to fix this error? I tried like hours and did not get any solution working.